# Perhaps or Maybe or I Guess/Think - which one is correct in formal (office) email writing

Tags: grammar, formality, email

**Background:**

> Boss: Did you get that X thing is done?
>
> Me: Yes, that's done.
>
> Boss: No that's not done, I am still getting calls from people asking for X?
>
> Me: Oh, **Perhaps/Maybe/I guess/I think** you are asking about Y thing.

Here I was chatting with my boss, I doubt what should I use out of these if I want to make it more formal chat/email?

If none are correct, please suggest.

Comment: "Thats"? I think, perhaps, that you should deal with that first — that's far more important.

Comment: David, what's wrong in that? Sorry, I didn't get what you mean. Are you saying I should use apostrophe s, and it is `that's` not `thats`. Right?

Comment: Right. You said it was a formal email. And my subjective answer to your question is there too.

Comment: Oh, please excuse me, thats me typing in hurry. :) I also type in hurry in formal emails but outlook won't let me send emails without fixing the spelling mistakes, so I am covered there.
Wow, I didnt notice. Your comment has hidden answer, very creative. However all readers might not understand it. So I request put it as an answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [interpersonal.se].

Comment: @CJDennis isn't it about using correct "grammar", "formality" and "email"?Had it been about how should I initiate the conversation with the manager then perhaps it is a question to go into Interpersonal Skills. This is what I think, but you decide.

Comment: Do people still use 'perhaps'? Sounds old-fashioned  or stilted.

Comment: "Is it possible that you're thinking of ..."

Comment: @Mitch perhaps vs. maybe: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=perhaps%2Cmaybe&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cperhaps%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmaybe%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @CJDennis NGrams doesn't tell you how people speak.

Comment: @Mitch No, but it's not uncorrelated either.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a far closer fit with the purview of 
Interpersonal Skills.SE.

Answer (score 1):

To be as polite as possible you want to keep the option that it was your fault, not his.
I would use Perhaps. 
"Perhaps you are talking about 'Y'" 
Or else "I think *you may* be talking about 'Y'"

With these you could add "I'm sure I took care of 'X' for this reason." But be sure X is not still out there.